# Proving that the kinetic energy of the gluon fields $G_{\mu}^{a}$ is $SU(3)$-invariant?

Tags: particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, gauge-invariance

In QCD, we introduce the gluon-fields $G_{\mu}^{a}$ when defining the covariant derivative $D_{\mu} \equiv \partial_{\mu} + ig_{S}G_{\mu}^{a}T^{a}$ to make the free-particle Lagrangian $
\mathcal L_{\text{free}} \equiv \bar{\psi}\left( i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu} - m\right)\psi$ $SU\left( 3\right)$-invariant. For the invariance to hold, the gluon fields $G_{\mu}^{a}$ have to transform as following: $$\left( G^{a}_{\mu} \right)' = G^{a}_{\mu} - \partial_{\mu}\alpha^{a}\left( x\right) - g_{S}f^{abc}\alpha^{b}\left(x\right)G_{\mu}^{c} \qquad [1]$$

Now, we also need a kinetic term for the gluon fields $G_{\mu}^{a}$:

$$\mathcal L_{\text{kin}} \equiv -\frac{1}{4}G^{a}_{\mu\nu}G^{a\mu\nu}, \qquad G^{a}_{\mu\nu}\equiv\partial_{\mu}G_{\nu}^{a}-\partial_{\nu}G_{\mu}^{a}-g_{S} f^{abc}G_{\mu}^{b}G_{\nu}^{c} \qquad [2].$$

I would like to show the $SU(3)$-invariance of $\mathcal L_{\text{kin}}$, but I fail along the way. I think my biggest problem is that I wrote down the complete expressions for $G^{a}_{\mu\nu}$ and also $G^{a\mu\nu}$, but I get *really long* expressions and I'm not sure what to do with these. I have terms $\propto \alpha^{c}G^{d\mu}\alpha^{d}G^{e\nu}$, and the same just with the indices $\mu$ and $\nu$ down, and I'm not sure what to do with them.

Could sb please guide me through the proof?

Comment: Be very mindful of the indices. Don't repete summed over indices many times, use different indices. Then juggle with them in ways that help you simplify your expression. Using summed over indices more than once would get you in trouble, like with the term you suggest $\alpha^{c}G^{d\mu}\alpha^{d}G^{e\nu}$. I don't see how the index $d$ could be summed over in that way. Moreover, remember that the structure constants are totally antisymmetric.

Comment: @G.Smith Good catch!

Comment: @Davide Morgante Okay, I see, maybe that was my mistake to use already summed over indices again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a tedious computation, if you want to perform it this way. I would propose an alternative approach (but if you're really interested in doing the calculation in this particular manner, I'll just erase this answer). My line of reasoning is the following: it is easily provable that $\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{kin}$ is invariant under the gauge transformation $(G_{\mu})^\prime= \mathsf{U} G_{\mu} \mathsf{U}^{\dagger}-\mathrm{i}/{g_S}\left(\partial_{\mu} \mathsf{U}\right) \mathsf{U}^{\dagger}$. What you wrote in [1] is actually the corresponding infinitesimal transformation of $G_\mu^a$ from $G_\mu=\sum_a G_\mu^a t^a$ (derivation sketched below, if interested). Thus, it seems reasonable to state that since $\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{kin}$ is invariant under the whole gauge transformation $\mathsf{U}=\mathsf{exp}\{\mathrm{i}g_S\alpha\}$, it should remain invariant under the infinitesimal $\mathsf{U}\approx 1+\mathrm{i}g_S\alpha$, which gives the transformation from [1].

(Gauge invariance under $\mathsf{SU}(3)$)

For a $\mathsf{SU}(3)$ transformation $\mathsf{U}=\mathsf{exp}\{\mathrm{i}g_S\alpha\}$, it is known that the gauge fields, which are elements of the Lie group $\mathsf{SU}(3)$, transform as

$$(G_{\mu})^\prime= \mathsf{U} G_{\mu} \mathsf{U}^{\dagger}-\frac{\mathrm{i}}{g_S}\left(\partial_{\mu} \mathsf{U}\right) \mathsf{U}^{\dagger}\tag{1}\label{gaugetransf}$$

whereas the field strength tensor $G_{\mu\nu}\equiv \partial_\mu G_\nu-\partial_\nu G_\mu+\mathrm{i}g_S[G_\mu,G_\nu]$ gauge transforms as

$$(G_{\mu \nu})^\prime = \mathsf{U} G_{\mu \nu} \mathsf{U}^{\dagger}$$

The kinetic term

$$\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{kin}=-\frac{1}{2}\mathsf{Tr}\{G_{\mu \nu}G^{\mu \nu}\}\tag{2}\label{lkin1}$$

is obviously gauge invariant due to the invariance of the trace under cyclic permutations and unitarity of the gauge transformation. This are all known facts.

(Infinitesimal gauge invariance for $\mathfrak{su}(3)$-valued gauge fields)

Instead of working with the gauge fields as elements of the group $\mathsf{SU}(3)$, it is customary to work with them in a particular representation of the associated algebra $\mathfrak{su}(3)$. As any Lie algebra, $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ is just the tangent vector space around identity at the underlying manifold of $\mathsf{SU}(3)$. If $t_a$ are the generators of the $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ algebra, they form a basis. Thus, any $\mathfrak{su}(3)$-valued gauge field may be expanded as

$$G_\mu=\sum_a G_\mu^a t^a$$

where of course $G_\mu$ will be representation dependent but $G_\mu^a$ won't. Consequently

$$G_{\mu\nu}=\sum_a G_{\mu\nu}^a t^a\quad\mathrm{where}\quad G_{\mu\nu}^a=\partial_{\mu} G_{\nu}^{a}-\partial_{\nu} G_{\mu}^{a}-g_S f^{a b c} G_{\mu}^{b} G_{\nu}^{c}$$

The last result may easily be deduced by using the $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ commutation relations $[t^a,t^b]=\mathrm{i}f^{abc}t^c$. This is precisely your equation [2].

Working infinitesimally and expanding the gauge transformation around identity, namely $\mathsf{U}\approx 1+\mathrm{i}g_S\alpha$ with $\alpha=\sum_a\alpha^a t^a$, the gauge transformation of the fields from \eqref{gaugetransf} becomes

$$(G_\mu)^\prime\approx G_\mu-\partial_\mu\alpha+\mathrm{i}g_S[\alpha,G_\mu]$$

which after using $G_\mu=\sum_a G_\mu^at^a$ and $\alpha=\sum_a \alpha^a t^a$ along with $[t^b,t^c]=-\mathrm{i}f^{abc}t^a$ gives exactly the transformation you wrote in [1]

$$(G^{a}_{\mu})^\prime\approx G^{a}_{\mu} - \partial_{\mu}\alpha^{a}\left( x\right) - g_{S}f^{abc}\alpha^{b}\left(x\right)G_{\mu}^{c}\tag{4}\label{infgaugetransf}$$

Since the kinetic Lagrangian from \eqref{lkin1} is gauge invariant under the $\mathsf{SU}(3)$ gauge transformation \eqref{gaugetransf}, the same Lagrangian expressed as

$$\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{kin}=-\frac{1}{2}G_{\mu\nu}^aG^{a\mu\nu}\underbrace{\mathsf{Tr}\{t^at^a\}}_{\displaystyle 1/2}$$

remains invariant under the infinitesimal variant of the gauge transformation of \eqref{gaugetransf}, as written in \eqref{infgaugetransf}.

Comment: I need to admit that I didn't understand every detail of your proof/argumentation (as my mathematical knowledge is not really deep), but I think I understand the rough idea and since I agree that the whole computation is quite tedious, I accept this answer. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I've entrered into too many Lie theory elements. The relevant thing is just that my equation (4), which is your equation [1], is actually an infinitesimal $\mathsf{SU}(3)$ gauge transformation (I tried to give the main steps in the proof for this) and since $\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{kin}$ is obviously invariant to the whole transformation, it's invariant also to the infinitesimal version of it. If something specific is unclear, feel free to ask away.

Comment: Thank you! For the moment, I don't have any follow-up questions. :)